# jQuery .hover() animation not smooth - Small bump/jerk on hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this simple jQuery hover effect, and it works, but not perfect - When you enter the list item(hover) the animation makes a small jerk/bump to the bottom, why is that? When leaving the element however, the animation is smooth (browser used - Chrome)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
<ul>
  <li><a>JP Links</a></li>
  <li><a>JP Middel</a></li>
  <li><a>JP Regs</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#div1 ul li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('a').animate({'top': '0'}, 'slow');
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).find('a').animate({'top': '75%'}, 'slow');
    }                 
);
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HTLRS/95/)

Comment: The box goes to the bottom first, that's what's giving you the impression of the bump...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you only wirte top: 0. Try writting top: 0% like this :

```
$(this).find('a').animate({'top': '0%'}, 'slow');
```

I can't tell why, but it work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `'0'` in the first function to `'10%'`  It is jerking down to start at 0, before it goes back up.